# Makefile warning about overriding recipe with grouped targets

Tags: makefile

The [Make documentation on grouped targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html) provides this example:

```
foo bar biz &: baz boz
    echo $^ > foo
    echo $^ > bar
    echo $^ > biz
```

That appears to work fine, however if I add a *second* grouped target:

```
foo bar biz &: baz boz
    echo $^ > foo
    echo $^ > bar
    echo $^ > biz

foo2 bar2 biz2 &: baz boz
    echo $^ > foo2
    echo $^ > bar2
    echo $^ > biz2
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Makefile:7: warning: overriding recipe for target '&'
Makefile:2: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '&'
```

Why?

Answer (score -2):

Ah it seems to be a bug in Make. I get that warning with version 4.2.1, but not version 4.4.90.

Comment: It is definitely not a bug in make.  The online manual documents the latest released version of GNU Make (obviously).  That is version 4.4.1: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/?C=M;O=D  You are using an older version 4.2.1 which was released over 7 years ago, in 2016.  This feature was added in version 4.3 (released in 2020).  You can find more information about what features were made available in which release here: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS?h=4.4.1

Comment: If you want to read documentation specific to your version of GNU Make you should look at the docs that came with your version: they should have been provided with whatever package you are using.